# One Jquery click function for multiply divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to use one click function for all of my div boxes. Did some research but still not able to get it working correctly. I'm new to programming so I might be going about this the wrong way, here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div id="test_1">
  <p class="example">display this text 1</p>
</div>

<div id="test_2">
  <p class="example">display this text 2</p>
</div>

<div id="test_3">
  <p class="example">display this text 3</p>
</div>
```

---

```
$('div[id^="test"]').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        test = $(this).parent().find('.example').attr("p")
        alert(test)
    })
})
```

I thought this would work but if I click on `div` test `2` or `3` the `alert` shows `"display this text 1"` instead of `"display this text 2"` or `"...3"`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.parent()`. Otherwise you're getting all the nested `.example` elements, and retrieving the `.attr('p')` of the first one.

```
$('div[id^="test"]').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var test = $(this).find('.example').attr("p")
        alert(test)
    })
})
```

Or shortened like this:

```
$('div[id^="test"]').click(function(){
    var test = $(this).find('.example').attr("p")
    alert(test)
})
```

---

Your question shows that you're getting a proper text result, though your code shows `.attr("p")`, which would not. I've left it the way it was to keep the code example the same.

Comment: That's right, the code in the question can't possibly give the stated result.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Yeah, I left it the same since it wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: Understood, I'm just agreeing with you IHL.

Answer (score 9):

Don't need `each`.

Bind click on `p` of each `div`

```
$('div[id^="test"] p').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qS4q7/)

Bind click on `div`s.

```
$('div[id^="test"]').click(function() {
    alert($('p', this).text());
});
```

`$('p', this).text()` is the same of `$(this).find('p').text()`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the divs into a class then select them like so:

```
<div class="clickable">
    <p>This is the first one</p>
</div>
<div class="clickable">
    <p>This is the second one</p>
</div>
<div class="clickable">
    <p>This is the third one</p>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickable').on('click',function() {
        alert($(this).children(':first').text());
    });
});​
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CX555/1/

Answer (score 0):

The true (and efficient) way to have one click for all your divs is to use event delegation:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="test_1">
  <p class="example">display this text 1</p>
</div>
<div id="test_2">
  <p class="example">display this text 2</p>
</div>
<div id="test_3">
  <p class="example">display this text 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('#wrap').on('click','div[id^="test"]',function(){
    test = $(this).find('.example').text();
    alert(test);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDX8C/

The single click is attached to the parent ("wrap"), and detects which child was actually clicked.